# Error running BrowserTest (Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: No schema ...)

Tags: 8, testing

I am working on a module [Rate Limiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate_limiter) and trying to improve the deprecated SimpleTest with BrowserTest. While doing so, I get the following error.

> C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8>.\vendor\bin\phpunit -c .\core\phpunit.xml.dist --filter testRateLimitConfigPageVisit .\modules\custom\rate_limiter\tests\src\Functional\RateLimiterConfigFormTest.php
>   PHPUnit 6.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

```
Testing Drupal\Tests\rate_limiter\Functional\RateLimiterConfigFormTest
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 56.75 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Drupal\Tests\rate_limiter\Functional\RateLimiterConfigFormTest::testRateLimitConfigPageVisit
Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\SchemaIncompleteException: No schema for rate_limiter.settings

C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\Development\ConfigSchemaChecker.php:88
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:111
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\Config.php:227
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller.php:334
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigInstaller.php:134
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Config\ConfigInstaller.php:75
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller.php:268
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller.php:83
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Test\FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php:437
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\tests\Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase.php:1026
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\core\tests\Drupal\Tests\BrowserTestBase.php:490
C:\Project\Sites\devdesktop\drupal8\modules\custom\rate_limiter\tests\src\Functional\RateLimiterConfigFormTest.php:32

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

The Schema file is: https://github.com/aneek/rate_limiter/blob/develop/config/install/rate_limiter.settings.yml

And the Test File is: https://github.com/aneek/rate_limiter/blob/develop/tests/src/Functional/RateLimiterConfigFormTest.php

What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Schema file is: https://github.com/aneek/rate_limiter/blob/develop/config/install/rate_limiter.settings.yml

No, that is not the schema file, that is the config file for which you need to create a configuration schema.

Tests by default enforce that your configuration has a schema, which is useful for supporting configuration translation and additional upcoming functionality like validation.

See [Configuration schema/metadata](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-schemametadata) for more information on how to create that.

Comment: ahh thanks, @Berdir for correcting me. I will have a look tomorrow and let you know.